# QT embedded show multi language at the same time(chinese, hebrew, thai)

Tags: qt, fonts, multilingual

i want to show multi languages(English, HEBREW, Thai, ARABIC, Chinese) as a selection list,
first , i'm using the debug message to show the support family, i don't know if this is a proper way to find the support font, please correct me if it's a wrong solution

```
/* output the support font */
QFontDatabase qfd ;
qDebug() << qfd.families(QFontDatabase::Hebrew);
qDebug() << qfd.families(QFontDatabase::Arabic);
qDebug() << qfd.families(QFontDatabase::Thai);
qDebug() << qfd.families(QFontDatabase::TraditionalChinese);
```

after get the debug message , i'm using tool "makeqpf" to create qpf2 files
found some QFont function about insert substitution
[QFont::insertSubstitution](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfont.html#insertSubstitution)  and [QFont::insertSubstitutions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfont.html#insertSubstitutions)
and i need to load all of them to show the correct words

> where DejaVu Sans for HEBREW, ARABIC  and waree for Thai

In this way, i can show the chinese, english, hebrew, arabic but not thai,

```
QFont font1("WenQuanYi Micro Hei [prerendered]",14,50,FALSE);
subs << "DejaVu Sans [prerendered]" << "Waree" ;
font1.insertSubstitutions("WenQuanYi Micro Hei [prerendered]", subs);
qApp->setFont(font1);

qDebug() << font1.family() ;
QStringList sl = font1.substitutions() ;
qDebug() << sl.isEmpty() ;
qDebug() << sl ;
qDebug() << font1.substitutes("WenQuanYi Micro Hei [prerendered]") ;
```

and i just make another test to change the font family

```
QFont font1("DejaVu Sans [prerendered]",14,50,FALSE);
subs << "WenQuanYi Micro Hei [prerendered]" << "Waree" ;
font1.insertSubstitutions("DejaVu Sans [prerendered]", subs);
qApp->setFont(font1);
```

if i insert "DejaVu Sans" first, when i open the multi language page,
the program crashed, i guess it's because the program can't show chinese and crashed,

i've also tried to read the "Thai" font "Waree" independently like below

```
QFont font1("Waree",14,50,FALSE);
```

in this way, i can see the "Thai" font in my program,
but only "Thai", (Hebrew, Arabic, Traditional Chinese) all remain in blank

and the final goal is to show all the language at the same time
so i need load waree and show it correctly, please help
and thanks for reading!

any reply will be appreciated!!